# pg_search_scope by two different column in one table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg-search

Why search by the second column from the current table doesn't work? Does anyone know how to fix that?

**model.rb**

```
  pg_search_scope :search,
              :against => [:name, :phone_number],
              using: { tsearch: { prefix: true, any_word: true } },
              associated_against: {
                :client => [:name, :phone_number]
              }
```

**console_log**

```
2.5.3 :060 > Client.search("Davis, Lorentzz")

=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Client id: 100, company_id: 8, name: "Davis, Lorentzz", email: "gdrgrd@fgrd.com", variety: "person", active: nil, created_at: "2019-01-29 11:50:17", updated_at: "2019-01-29 11:50:20", phone_number: "1456455453", organisation: "", office_note: "", special_note: "Special Davis">]> 

2.5.3 :061 > Client.search("1456455453")

=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Comment: Curious why are you adding `associated_against` and `against` for same columns?

Comment: Could you show search logs ?

Comment: can you try with `multisearch_options` ?